# How to show tooltip programmatically in Angular?

Tags: angular, tooltip

How can i trigger to show a tooltip when hovering other element? without playing with position and css?
So let's say i'm hovering the textarea - my goal is to trigger the tooltip for the label at the same position - as if i hovered the label.

[image]

I'm using Angular, i have the following markup :

```
<div style="margin: 20px">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 300px">
    <span
      class="label"
      [tooltip]="'John ID 123456'"
      style="width: fit-content"
      >User Name: John Denver</span
    >
    <br>
    <textarea
      class="text-area"
      (mouseenter)="showTooltip(true)"
      (mouseleave)="showTooltip(false)"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js

```
export class AppComponent {
  public isShowTooltip = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false);
  ngOnInit() {}
  showTooltip(val: boolean) {
    this.isShowTooltip.next(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please explain why you are unwilling to use CSS for that? Without knowing that, several plausible responses would be a waste of time for you and the person who submitted the answer.

Comment: `*ngIf="(isShowTooltip | async)"`..?

Comment: Just use `title` on your elemen:
e.g:  <p title="this is where you put title">test</p>

Comment: @JSmart523 - Thanks for your time, the reason i would rather use JS is because the component i'm using is generic - so i would never know the exact position to assign.... i was thinking of add id to each label and try to append the tooltip... but no success so far

Comment: @ParsaArvaneh - thanks - i already tried - the tooltip is triggered but hovering event - simple IF won't do....

Comment: So you want to show tooltip only when text is timed(like thi...)?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, you want to show your tooltip when text is trimmed.
e.g: this txt is .... .
You can make a directive to do this:

```
export class ShowTextIfEllipsisActivatedDirective {
constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

@HostListener('mouseenter')
public onMouseEnter(): void {
    const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    if (element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
        element.title = element.textContent;
    } else if (element.title) element.removeAttribute('title');
}
```

Directive is executed when element that it is assigned to is created. This code  simply says that element is gonna have a `mouseenter` event, and if the text is bigger that the box that it is in it, it's gonna add `title` attribute to it. Of course it requires you to make the text ellipsis using css.
your css code:

```
.my-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20ch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - what i meant was the following scenario: There is a component with label and textarea, so when i hover the textarea i want to show the tooltip in the label - and not on the textarea - now - it's sounds rather simple - i could simply wrap the entire component with tooltip - but then what will happens is that i wouldn't be able to control the position of the tooltip....because i will be shown according to the component width - and NOT only for the label width - as expected. I'll add more instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Got it :

```
<div style="margin: 20px">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 300px">
    <pre>{{ isShowTooltip | async }}</pre>
    <span #label
      class="label"
      [tooltip]="'John ID 123456'"
      style="width: fit-content"
      >User Name: John Denver</span
    >
    <br>
    <textarea
      class="text-area"
      (mouseenter)="showTooltip(true)"
      (mouseleave)="showTooltip(false)"
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

export class AppComponent {
  public isShowTooltip = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false);
  @ViewChild('label') label: ElementRef;

  showTooltip(val: boolean) {
    // Create a new MouseEvent

    setTimeout(() => {
      if (val) {
        const hoverEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseenter', {
          bubbles: true, // Allow the event to bubble up the DOM tree
          cancelable: true, // Allow the event to be canceled
          view: window, // The view (window in this case)
        });
        this.label.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(hoverEvent);
      } else {
        const leaveEvent = new MouseEvent('mouseleave', {
          bubbles: true, // Allow the event to bubble up the DOM tree
          cancelable: true, // Allow the event to be canceled
          view: window, // The view (window in this case)
        });
        // Dispatch the hover event on the element
        this.label.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(leaveEvent);
      }

      //  this.isShowTooltip.next(val);
    });
  }
}
```